# Uploading image from android phone to laptop takes too long ,finally uploaded it says"Windows photo viewer can't display because file is empty"

Tags: php, android, wamp

I am trying to develop camera based equation solver that requires uploading a camera clicked image onto the local server using wamp.This is my android code. It has two buttons one to upload a handwritten equation camera image and the other to upload printed equation camera image. Depending on the button pressed a particular .php file will be executed from my laptop to store the uploaded image in a folder in c:/wamp/www/upload. Currently I am testing the upload part with the button for handwritten equation image.

package EqSolver.example;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;
import org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

public class EqSolverActivity extends Activity {

    private SurfaceView m_Preview = null;
    private SurfaceHolder m_PreviewHolder = null;
    private Camera m_Camera = null;
    private Builder m_Builder;
    private Button m_QueryButton = null;
    private int m_QueryType;

    public static final String QUERY_IMAGE_1 = "query_image_1";
    public static final String QUERY_IMAGE_2 = "query_image_2";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* Use full screen and remove window title */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /* Create message dialog for showing text */
        m_Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        m_Builder.setTitle("Solution");

        /* Class to take care of the photo application */
        m_Preview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView01);
        m_PreviewHolder = m_Preview.getHolder();
        m_PreviewHolder.addCallback(surfaceCallback);
        m_PreviewHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        /* Add button for query/add */
        m_QueryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.solveHW);
        m_QueryButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                m_QueryType = 1;
                takePicture();
            }
        });
        m_QueryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.solveP);
        m_QueryButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                m_QueryType = 0;
                takePicture();
            }
        });

        m_QueryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        m_QueryButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView editView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.equation);
                Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
                Log.v("Final Equation: ", editView.getText().toString());
                editView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                byte[] imageBytes = editView.getText().toString().getBytes();
                ServerPushAsync mAsync = new ServerPushAsync(imageBytes, -1,
                        QUERY_IMAGE_2);
                mAsync.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
            m_QueryType = 0;
            takePicture();
            return (true);
        }
        return (super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
    }

    private void takePicture() {
        m_Camera.takePicture(null, null, photoCallback);
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback photoCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        private Camera m_Camera;

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera m_Camera) {
            /* Downsize the image from the camera */
            Bitmap bImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            bImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bImage, 640, 480, false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream oData = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, oData);
            this.m_Camera = m_Camera;

            /* Query image */
            ServerPushAsync mAsync = new ServerPushAsync(oData.toByteArray(),
                    m_QueryType, QUERY_IMAGE_1);
            mAsync.execute();

        }
    };

    /*
     * COPY THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION TO YOUR CLASS IF YOU PLAN TO USE TEXT
     * RECOGNITION SERVICE
     */
    /* Send HTTP POST request with image data to image recognition server */
    public static String QueryImage1(byte[] bData, int iQueryType) {
        /* Setup http objects */
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost;
        if (iQueryType == 1) {
            httpPost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://192.168.1.5/EqSolverProcessWritten.php");
        } else {
            httpPost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://192.168.1.5/EqSolverProcessPrinted.php");
        }
        ByteArrayEntity bEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(bData);
        String sResult = null;

        try {
            /* Construct data */
            httpPost.setEntity(bEntity);
            /* Send HTTP request */
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            /* Get the text results from the response */
            BufferedReader hBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuilder sInputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                String sInputLine = null;
                while ((sInputLine = hBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    sInputBuffer.append(sInputLine + "\n");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
            sResult = sInputBuffer.toString();

            Log.v("RECEIVED", sResult);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return sResult;
    };

    public static String QueryImage2(byte[] bData) {
        /* Setup http objects */
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "http://192.168.1.5/EqSolverSolve.php");
        String test = "THIS IS A TEST";
        ByteArrayEntity bEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(bData);

        String sResult = null;

        try {
            /* Construct data */
            httpPost.setEntity(bEntity);
            /* Send HTTP request */
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            /* Get the text results from the response */
            BufferedReader hBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuilder sInputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                String sInputLine = null;
                while ((sInputLine = hBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    sInputBuffer.append(sInputLine + "\n");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
            sResult = sInputBuffer.toString();

            Log.v("RECEIVED", sResult);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return sResult;
    };

    SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            m_Camera = Camera.open();
            /* Set the camera parameters to take the smallest image as possible */
            Camera.Parameters currentParameters = m_Camera.getParameters();
            m_Camera.setParameters(currentParameters);
            try {
                m_Camera.setPreviewDisplay(m_PreviewHolder);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("PictureDemo-surfaceCallback",
                        "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
                Toast.makeText(EqSolverActivity.this, t.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {
            Camera.Parameters currentParameters = m_Camera.getParameters();
            currentParameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
            currentParameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
            m_Camera.setParameters(currentParameters);
            m_Camera.startPreview();
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            m_Camera.stopPreview();
            m_Camera.release();
            m_Camera = null;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Asynchronous task ... Runs in background thread , does not block the UI
     */

    private class ServerPushAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private byte[] bData;
        private int iQueryType;
        private String QueryImageType;
        private AlertDialog pg;

        public ServerPushAsync(byte[] bData, int iQueryType,
                String QueryImageType) {
            this.bData = bData;

            this.iQueryType = iQueryType;
            this.QueryImageType = QueryImageType;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pg = new ProgressDialog(EqSolverActivity.this);
            pg.setCancelable(false);
            ((ProgressDialog) pg)
                    .setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pg.setMessage("Pushing image to server...");
            pg.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String response = "";
            if (QueryImageType.equals(QUERY_IMAGE_1)) {
                response = EqSolverActivity.QueryImage1(bData, iQueryType);
            } else {
                // query_image_2
                response = EqSolverActivity.QueryImage2(bData);
            }

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

            if (pg != null) {
                pg.dismiss();
            }
            if (response == null) {
                response = "something went wrong";
            }
            if (response.equals("")) {
                response = "something went wrong";
                Log.e("ERROR", "NO response captured");
            }

            if (QueryImageType.equals(QUERY_IMAGE_1)) {
                /* Display equation and wait for confirmation from user */
                TextView editView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.equation);
                Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
                editView.setText(response);
                editView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                m_Camera.startPreview();
            } else {
                TextView editView = null;
                // query_image_2
                m_Builder.setMessage((QueryImage2(editView.getText().toString()
                        .getBytes())));
                editView.setText("");
                m_Builder.show();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This is my php code to serve the handwritten equation.
EqSolverHandwritten.php

```
   <?php

$command = "del /F C:\wamp\www\upload\tessLineImg.txt"; 
exec($command);
$command = "del /F C:\wamp\www\upload\lineImgCorr.jpg";
exec($command);
$command = "del /F C:\wamp\www\upload\TessOutput.txt";
exec($command);
$command = "del /F C:\wamp\www\upload\svmOutput.txt";
exec($command);

/* Get input and configuration parameters */
$bData = file_get_contents('php://input');

/* Setup time stamp for different queries */
 $fCurrTime  = time(true); 
 $fJune01    = 1338447600;
 $fDiffSec   = $fCurrTime - $fJune01;
 $fHour      = floor( ($fDiffSec%86400)/3600);
 $fMinute    = floor( ($fDiffSec%3600)/60 );
 $sTimeStamp = sprintf('%02d%02d_%.0f', $fHour, $fMinute, $fDiffSec%10);

//$sTimeStamp = time();

/* Setup file names and upload paths */
$sInputFileJpg      = './inputImg_'.$sTimeStamp.'.jpg';
$photo_upload_path  = './upload/'.$sInputFileJpg;

/* Save the uploaded jpg image to file */
file_put_contents( $photo_upload_path, $bData);

?>
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Hye Cleb the Image I am uploading on my localserver from android browser takes too long to upload and finally when it gets uploaded and I try to open it It says "Windows photo viewer can't display this picture because the file is empty". I guess the file is not getting transferred properly... and currently I am heading clueless of what to do

Comment: ' Log.v("RECEIVED", sResult);'. What does that print? Why did you post so much irrelevant code? Why do we have to dig through that all? For two pictures that fail. Why twice the same?

Comment: `It has two buttons one to upload a handwritten equation camera image and the other to upload printed equation camera image. ` ??? One is for an image and the other for a text as far as i can see. Please explain.what a `handwritten equation camera image ` would be.

Comment: Never saw `ByteArrayEntity` used before. So i gave it a try with the now deprecated 'DefaultHttpClient' and `HttpPost`. Used your code to upload. Can only say that it works ok with `file_get_contents('php://input');` to receive an image or a text.

Comment: @greenapps both buttons are for image only.One where handwritten text/digits image is captured and send to server and second computer printed text/digits is captured and sent to server. Currently my files are not getting uploaded and I dont get any error in logcat. I tried to restart the wamp server and gave it a try again. I don't know exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: `byte[] imageBytes = editView.getText().toString().getBytes();` Why do you call a TextView an editView? But you extract text. Not an image. So please elaborate what is happening here.

Comment: @greenapps The captured image is sent to localserver. Using image processing the recognized text and digits are sent back to user for confirmation wherein the user can edit the wrongly recognized character and than send back to server for further calculations.

Comment: Please react on my comment. I suggested that `byte[] imageBytes = editView.getText().toString().getBytes();` was no image at all but a text.

Comment: @greenapps...This is a TextView which is named as equation in my layouts.

So what that line does is it gets whatever text that TextView has and converts and stores that text(which is a string type)  byteArray.... I would be glad if you can throw some light of why the image is not getting displayed

Comment: So it is indeed a text that you want to upload. Well then i wonder why you talk about an image again. You could try to display that text then. But not an image.

Comment: My only problem is uploading the image that I click. So I be glad if you can help me in that aspect :)

Comment: Now if you could start reacting to the point to my comments... If does not make much fun if you dont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved the error thought to post it here after a long time.I just had to turn off my firewall and it worked like magic :D !